# Develop Against Simple Target Platform configuration

Tags: eclipse-plugin, tycho

In the Tycho documentation the ["simple target platform configuration"](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform#Simple_target_platform_configuration) is the first entry for "Target platform configuration":

```xml
<repository>
   <id>eclipse-indigo</id>
   <url>http://download.eclipse.org/releases/indigo</url>
   <layout>p2</layout>
</repository>
```

Let's assume that's because it's the default way for setting a target platform, an assumption supported by the fact that the [Eclipse guys](https://git.eclipse.org/c/) seem to do it that way.

How do you develop against a module with a target platform set that way? Normally you'd have a "*.target" file somewhere and set it, then start your tests / product / whatever.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure why the 'simple target platform configuration' is mentioned first. Even though it might be the simplest form to set up, it is of limited use for real-world use cases.

Most Eclipse projects I know of which consume Eclipse platform bundles use target platform definitions, both within the IDE and in their Tycho build.

If you are using a target platform definition in your IDE (.target file), you should also instruct Tycho to use that target platform (see also 'Which approach shall I use for the target platform of my project?').

This way, you only need to maintain a single source of dependencies. Furthermore, you can define different target platform definitions and thus verify that your code works well across different versions of the same target platform.

With a *simple target platform configuration* you would need to manually keep the target platform of the IDE in sync with the Tycho target platform.

The ['Target files'](https://wiki.eclipse.org/Tycho/Target_Platform#Target_files) section of the above wiki page explains the details and differences to the IDE

Does that answer your question?